# Distinct n numbers so that sum equals to N

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I want to find n distinct numbers in the range from 1 to N, so that their sum is equal to N. e.g.

```
n = 3, N = 10: the numbers will be (2, 3, 5);
n = 4, N = 10: the numbers will be (1, 2, 3, 4).
```

While finding out all the possible combinations for this problem will take exponential time, I am looking for the "smallest" combination, i.e. the largest number is the smallest. For example,

in the case where `n = 4, and N = 12`, both `(6, 3, 2, 1) and (5, 4, 2, 1)` can be the solution, but I am only interested in `(5, 4, 2, 1)`.

For this problem, will there be an algorithm with a better time complexity? I heard about the logarithmic merge, but not sure how that can be applied here.

If any details of the problem needs to be specified please let me know. And always, any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: For n = 3, N = 10, I think the solution should be `2, 3, 5`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a simple greedy algorithm for this problem.

At first, there are n elements in ascending order, in order for them to be distinct, each element should be greater than its predecessor by at least one.

so, we have

`1, 2, 3 ... , n`

Now, the sum of all `n` number is `n*(n + 1)/2`

What is left is `left = N - n*(n + 1)/2`

In order to keep the last element as small as possible, we need to scatter the `left` difference to all numbers

so, we have

`1 + left/n, 2 + left/n, ..., n + left/n`

If `left % n != 0`, we just need to add extra 1 to the last `left % n` elements.

**Note**: if `N < n*(n + 1)/2`, there is no solution

Example:

So, for n = 4 and N = 12

```
First, we start with

1, 2, 3, 4

left = 12 - (4*5/2) = 2

So, now we have

1 + (2/4), 2 + (2/4), 3 + (2/4), 4 + (2/4) = 1, 2, 3, 4

As left % n = 2
Finally, we have

1, 2, 3 + 1, 4 + 1 = 1, 2, 4, 5
```

Similarly, for n = 3, N = 10

```
First, we start with

1, 2, 3

left = 10 - (3*4/2) = 4

So, now we have

1 + (4/3), 2 + (4/3), 3 + (4/3) = 2, 3, 4

As left % n = 1
Finally, we have

2, 3, 4 + 1 = 2, 3, 5
```

Pseudo-code, time complexity O(n)

```java
int[]result = new int[n];
int left = N - n*(n + 1)/2;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    result[i] = i + 1 + left/n;
    if(i >= n - (left % n)){//Add extra one for last left % n elements
        result[i]++;
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: You can also add that if left is 0 return result and for left < 0 there is no answer ;).

Comment: Simple and Clever!

Comment: Thank you so much and it is very clear and answers the problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function `f(n, N, sum)` - it will return result that will show you the possibility of taking `n` elements from the range `1` to `N` summing up to `sum`.

At least now you can determine if the solution exists simply calling `f(n, N, N)`.

Let's say that for a given `n`, `N` and `sum` the problem `p(n,N,sum)` has a solution and `x` is the smallest largest number in result. Then the problem `p(n',N',sum')` with `n'=n-1`, `N'=x-1`, `sum'=sum-x` should also have a solution. The problem `p(0,N,0)` always have a solution and it is a base of the induction.

Function `f(n, N, sum)` will actually return the smallest number `x` from the range `1` to `N` that can be part of the solution (else it should return `-1` or something indicating solution absence). We may try every number from `1` to `N` as an `x` and check if `f(n - 1, x - 1, sum - x)` has a solution.

The key thing here is to use **memoization** in order not to calculate the same function many times. Just remember found `x`. Memorizing every possible input combination will take at most `O(n * N * N)` space and same `O(n * N * N)` time to be computed. Also, there would be no solution if `sum>N*(N+1)/2` we may instantly prune such calls. This is polynomial time/space complexity which is better than exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to break the problem, suppose we have n distinct numbers in between [1, N]. what is the minimum possible sum, it would be the sum of first n natural numbers i.e

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n
```

the maximum number possible would be

```
(N-n+1) + (N-n+2) + (N-n+3) + ... + (N-n+n)
```

> Note all sum in between min and max value can be made using n numbers

Now as it is checked if the value is possible or not we can do. Suppose we take the numbers 1 to n. current sum **S** is equal to

```
S = 1 + 2 + ... + n
```

if I add x to each element it would become

```
S = 1 + 2 + ... + n + x*n <= N
```

If we select the maximum possible such x then the sum would be reachable by adding 1 element to all numbers starting from the greatest until the desired sum is reached(i.e at most n-1 numbers). This would then give me a valid answer.

So if the answer is possible it would be

1. take elements from 1 to n
2. add x to each element
3. from the greatest number keep adding 1 until the sum is reached

Answer (score 0):

This can be calculated almost instantly.  The answer will always either look like a run of numbers centered around `N/n`, or else a run of numbers with essentially the same center, with a gap of 1 somewhere in the middle.

So calculate that middle, then calculate whether and where you need that gap.  Then you're done.

If `n` is odd, then the middle is `N/n` (assuming integer division) with enough shifted 1 to the right to account for the remainder.  So, for example, if `N` is 10000 and `n` is 17, then the middle is 588, and your starting range is 588 ± (17-1)/2 which is 580-596.  But the remainder is 4, so shift 4 over and and your answer will be 580-592, 594-597.

If `n` is the middle starts on a half number.  So the middle is `(N-n/2)/n + 0.5`.  So, for example, if `N` is 10000 and `n` is 18, then the middle is 555.5 and your starting range is 555.5 ± (18-1)/2 which is 547-564.  But that division had a remainder of 1 so we get an answer of 547-563, 565.